# No such column when creating an alias for a model association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many

I want to create a one to many association between a `User` and `Task` model. In my user model I'd like to give it the alias of `owner` and refer to the user's tasks as `owned_tasks`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owned_tasks, class_name: "Task", as: :owner
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    #owner_id
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
end
```

When I try and retrieve the list of tasks as so I run into this error:

```
user = User.first
user.owned_tasks

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tasks.owner_type: SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."owner_id" = ? AND "tasks"."owner_type" = ?
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tasks.owner_type: SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."owner_id" = ? AND "tasks"."owner_type" = ?
```

Why is it referring to `owner_type` when there's no attribute of that name stored in my database?

Comment: remove the `as: :owner`... why it is needed ? Are you going to do `polymorphic` associations ?

Comment: didn't get you? What you meant ? ;)

Comment: Wouldn't it also return info when using `task.owner`?

Comment: everything will work.. just remove the `as:` thing..

Comment: Well after removing `as:` I get this error: `no such column: tasks.user_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your corrected version :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: :owner_id
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    #owner_id
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
end
```

## Why need `:foreign_key` option ?

> [Specify the foreign key](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the name of this class in lower-case and `_id` suffixed. So a Person class that makes a `has_many` association will use `person_id` as the default `:foreign_key`.
>
> [Specify the foreign key](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the name of the association with an `_id` suffix. So a class that defines a `belongs_to :person` association will use `person_id` as the default `:foreign_key`. Similarly, `belongs_to :favorite_person, class_name: "Person"` will use a foreign key of `favorite_person_id`.

Comment: Thanks so much. You must've been reading my mind because I was just about to ask why a `foreign_key: :owner_id` is needed for both models instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails the `:as` option is used when setting up [polymorphic relationships](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). In a polymorphic relationship the *other* can be several different models. That's why the `tasks.owner_type` column is required - it tells Rails which table to look at when loading the `owner` relation.

The solution is to either create a `tasks.owner_type` column or to setup the relationship as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :owned_tasks, 
             class_name: "Task", 
             foreign_key: :owner_id
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
end
```